# How polynomial interpolation of polynomial multiplication algorithm works?

Tags: algorithms, polynomials, fast-fourier-transform

I'm trying to apply the following algorithm from DPV's textbook to an example to see how it works. First, the algorithm is as following:

> **Algorithm** [DPV, p. 60]
>
> **Input:** Coefficients of two polynomials. A(x) and B(x), of degree d.
>
> **Output:** Their product $C = A . B$
>
> - Selection: Pick some points $x_0, x_1, x_2, ..., x_{n-1}$ where $n\geq 2d+1$
> - Evaluation: Compute $A(x_0), A(x_1), ...., A(x_{n-1})$ and $B(x_0), B(x_1), ...., B(x_{n-1})$
> - Multiplication: Compute $C(x_k)=A(x_k) \times B(x_k)$ for all $k=0, 1, ..., n-1$
> - Interpolation: Recover $C(x) = c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + .... + c_{2d} x^{2d}$

Now, I took an example $A(x) = 3x^2 -4x + 1$ and $B(x) = x-2$. The output should be $C(x) = 3x^3 - 10 x^2 + 9 x -2$. Now, the algorithm first choose an arbitrary points, so I will choose the following: $x_0 = 1, x_1 = 3, x_2=6,$ and $x_3 = 9$. Now, we evaluate the A(x_i) and B(x_i) for $i=0, 1, 2$ and $3$. Thus, $A(x_0) = 0, A(x_1) = 16, A(x_2) = 85, A(x_3)=208, B(x_0) = -1, B(x_1) = -2, B(x_2) = -5,$ and $B(x_3)=-8$. Thus, we compute $C(x_i)$ for $i=0, 1, 2,$ and $3$. So, we get $C(x_0) = 0, C(x_1) = -32, C(x_2)=-425,$ and $C(x_3) = -1664$.

Now, I have $x_0=1, x_1=3, x_2=6,$ and $x_3=9$ and the corresponding $C(x_0) = 0, C(x_1) = -32, C(x_2) = -425,$ and $C(x_3)=-1664$. This I will apply the polynomial interpolation to get the output. I used [this page](https://www.dcode.fr/lagrange-interpolating-polynomial) to compute the coefficients of C(x). So, I got the output as following: $-3x^3 + 7x^2 - 5x + 1$ but it should be this one: $C(x) = 3x^3 - 10 x^2 + 9 x -2$. So, **where is the problem?** Is it because finding interpolation cannot be in exact so the coefficient is an approximation to the exact one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing, you can use SageMath very easily;

you had erros on

$$A(x_0) = 0, A(x_1) = 16, A(x_2) = 85, A(x_3)=208, \\B(x_0) = -1, \color{red}{B(x_1) = -2}, \color{red}{B(x_2) = -5},\color{red}{B(x_3) = 8}$$

```
    R = PolynomialRing(QQ, 'x')
    A = 3 *x^2-4*x+1
    B = x -2
    a0 = A(1)
    a1 = A(3)
    a2 = A(6)
    a3 = A(9)
    b0 = B(1)
    b1 = B(3)
    b2 = B(6)
    b3 = B(9)
    c0 = a0*b0
    c1 = a1*b1
    c2 = a2*b2
    c3 = a3*b3
    
    print( a0,a1,a2,a3)
    print( b0,b1,b2,b3)
    print( c0,c1,c2,c3)
    
    f = R.lagrange_polynomial([(1,c0),(3,c1),(6,c2),(9,c3)])
    f
```

Outputs

```
0 16 85 208
-1 1 4 7
0 16 340 1456
3*x^3 - 10*x^2 + 9*x - 2
```

Comment: Thank you Kelalaka! So it was just some wrong numbers.

Comment: Yes, if you need to do only hand, double-check everything.